# How to adjust GLB object based on the available surface area in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, augmented-reality, arkit, arcore

I am using `ar_flutter_plugin: ^0.7.3` to display .GLB models. I can display .GLB models by loading it from app's document directory. Currently my code can able to display the .GLB object when I tap on the surface point and for that `arSessionManager.onPlaneOrPointTap` callback is used. but I want to display my object when proper surface is detected and also object should be placed in a surface with proper dimensions.

I am using the callback `onPlaneOrPointTap` that gives me the list of `ARHitTestResult` and by using it, I am placing the object using `arObjectManager.addNode()` method.
But I can't find the callback like `onPlaneDetected` or `onSurfaceDetected`.

So is there any way to achieve this?